# opl cannot extract expression error in CPLEX

Tags: expression, extract, cplex, opl

I get this error,"opl cannot extract expression", for some expression in my objective function when I am running the code in CPLEX. My code is as follow:

```
 /*********************************************
 * OPL 6.3 Model
 * Author: hp
 * Creation Date: Dec 14, 2016 at 6:16:18 PM
 *********************************************/

//Distribution Centers
int J=...;
range DC=1..J;
//Customers
int I=...;
range Customers=J+1..I;
//Vehicles
int V=...;
range Vehicle=1..V;
//Time Periods
int T=...;
range TP=1..T;
//Nodes
range Nodes=1..I;
//Operating Cost
int FCj[DC]=...;
//Vehicle_Cap
int VehicleCap[Vehicle]=...;
//Depot_Cap
int DepotCap=...;
//Transportation_Cost
float Cij[Nodes][Nodes]=...;
//TransCost_to_factory
float Cj[DC]=...;
//OrderCost
float OrderC[DC]=...;
//Demand
int Demand[Customers][TP]=...;

//HoldingCost
int HoldingC[DC]=...;
//return rate
float r=...;
//probability of quality problem
float w=...;
//repairing cost
float repairC=...;
//Manufacturing Cost
float m=...;
//repackaging cost
float repackagingC=...;
float Hivalue=...;

// optimal order
dvar int+ Qjt[DC][TP];

//DC
dvar boolean Xj[DC];
//DC allocation to customers
dvar boolean Yij[DC][Customers];
//Vehicle route
dvar boolean Xijvt[Nodes][Nodes][Vehicle][TP];
//sub-tour elimination
dvar int+    M[Customers][Vehicle][TP];

//Final Inventory
dvar int+   Sjt[DC][0..T];

//order decision variable
//dvar boolean Zjt[DC][TP];


//Varaible
// Total Costs

 dexpr float TotalHoldingandOrderingCosts=sum (j in DC, t in TP) HoldingC[j]*Sjt[j][t]+sum (j in DC,t in TP) OrderC [j]* Qjt[j][t];
 dexpr float TotalDepotOperatingCost= sum (j in DC) Xj[j]*FCj[j];
 dexpr float TotalTransCostFactorytoDC= sum (j in DC, t in TP) Cj[j]*Qjt[j][t];
 dexpr float TotalTransCostDCtoCustomer= sum (i in Nodes, j in Nodes, v in Vehicle, t in TP) Cij[i][j]*Xijvt[i][j][v][t];
 dexpr float TotalTransCostDCToFactory= sum (j in DC, t in TP) w*r*Qjt[j][t]*Cj[j];
 dexpr float TotalManufacturingCost= sum (i in Customers, t in TP) Demand[i][t]*m;
 dexpr float TotalReworkingCost= sum (j in DC, t in TP) w*r*repairC*sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i];
 dexpr float TotalRepackagingCost= sum (j in DC, t in TP) r*(1-w)*repackagingC*sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i];

 //Objective Function

 minimize TotalHoldingandOrderingCosts+TotalDepotOperatingCost+TotalTransCostFactorytoDC+
          TotalTransCostDCtoCustomer+TotalTransCostDCToFactory+TotalManufacturingCost+
          TotalReworkingCost+TotalRepackagingCost;

 subject to{

const1: forall (i in Customers){
  sum (j in DC)Yij[j][i]==1;}


Const2: forall (j in DC){
  sum (i in Customers)Yij[j][i]<=Xj[j]*Hivalue;}


Const3: forall (i in Customers) {
  sum (j in Nodes, v in Vehicle, t in TP) Xijvt [i][j][v][t]==1;}


Const4: forall (i in Nodes, v in Vehicle, t in TP) {
  sum (j in Nodes) Xijvt[i][j][v][t]-sum (j in Nodes) Xijvt[i][j][v][t]==0;}


Const5: forall (v in Vehicle, t in TP) {
  sum (i in Customers, j in DC)Xijvt[j][i][v][t]<=1; }


Const6: forall (v in Vehicle, t in TP) {
  sum (j in Nodes, i in Customers) Demand[i][t]*Xijvt[i][j][v][t]<=VehicleCap[v];}


Const7: forall (j in DC, t in TP) {
  sum (i in Customers) Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i]<=Xj[j]*DepotCap;}


Const8: forall (i in Customers, j in DC, v in Vehicle, t in TP){
  sum (g in Nodes) Xijvt[i][g][v][t]+sum (g in Nodes)Xijvt[g][j][v][t]-Yij[j][i]>=1;}


Const9: forall (i in Customers, h in Customers, v in Vehicle, t in TP){
  M[i][v][t]-M[h][v][t]+I*Xijvt[i][h][v][t]<=I-1;}


//Const10: forall (j in DC, t in TP){
 // sum (i in Customers) Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i]<=Qjt[j][t];}


//Const11: forall (j in DC, t in TP){
  //Zjt[j][t]<=Xj[j]*Hivalue;}


Const10: forall (j in DC){
  Sjt[j][0]==0;}


Const11: forall (j in DC){  
  Sjt[j][1]==Sjt[j][0]+Qjt[j][1]-sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][1]*Yij[j][i];}


Const13: forall (j in DC, t in 2..T){
  Sjt[j][t]==Sjt[j][t-1]+Qjt[j][t]-sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i]+
  sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t-1]*Yij[j][i]*r*(1-w);}


Const14: forall (j in DC, t in TP){
  Qjt[j][t] <= Hivalue*Xj[j]    ;}
}
execute DISPLAY {
      writeln("TotalHoldingandOrderingCosts=", TotalHoldingandOrderingCosts);
      writeln("TotalDepotOperatingCost=",TotalDepotOperatingCost);
      writeln("TotalTransCostFactorytoDC=",TotalTransCostFactorytoDC);
      writeln("TotalTransCostDCtoCustomer=",TotalTransCostDCtoCustomer);
      writeln("TotalTransCostDCToFactory=",TotalTransCostDCToFactory);
      writeln("TotalManufacturingCost=",TotalManufacturingCost);
      writeln("TotalReworkingCost=",TotalReworkingCost); 
      writeln( "TotalRepackagingCost=", TotalRepackagingCost);
        }   

    * OPL 6.3 Data
 * Author: hp
 * Creation Date: Dec 14, 2016 at 6:16:18 PM
 *********************************************/
J=2;
I=6;
V=3;
T=3;
r=0.2;
w=0.85;

FCj=[500 700];
VehicleCap=[600 600 600];
DepotCap=1000;
Cij=[[0 100 200 400 500 200]
     [200 0 100 300 100 300]
     [150 200 0 100 200 500]
     [100 200 200 0 100 100]
     [100 100 100 200 0 800]
     [300 350 250 150 100 0]];
Cj=[1 2];
OrderC=[0.2 0.1];
Demand=[[100 73 60]
        [50 40 68]
        [80 95 74]
        [30 68 94]];
HoldingC=[3 5];
repairC=0.5;
repackagingC=0.2;
m=2;
Hivalue=100000000;
```

It is confusing; I do not what the problem is. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, can you also attach your .dat ? regards

Comment: Hi, I made some changes to my model and these errors resolved; however, there are still conflicts between constraints that I know where the problem is about. It is for this expression:
 sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t-1]*Yij[j][i]*r*(1-w) in Constraints 13 
because when I remove this part, the model runs without any errors or conflicts. This expression states that returned products from previous time period can be packed again and add to inventory to be sold in current time period.

Comment: I edit the model in the first comment and add .dat.

Answer (score 0):

to get some useful relaxation you could rewrite const13 into

```
forall (j in DC, t in 2..T){
  const13a:Sjt[j][t]<=Sjt[j][t-1]+Qjt[j][t]-sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i]+
  sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t-1]*Yij[j][i]*r*(1-w);}

  forall (j in DC, t in 2..T){
  const13b:Sjt[j][t]>=Sjt[j][t-1]+Qjt[j][t]-sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t]*Yij[j][i]+
  sum(i in Customers)Demand[i][t-1]*Yij[j][i]*r*(1-w);}
```

regards